# Make required field to Gift Option in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, forms, fieldsets, required

I enable gift option from magento 2 admin. Now i want to make required. field on cart page.

I found that template is coming from `vendor/magento/module-gift-message/view/frontend/web/template/gift-message-form.html`

I know how we override html files but don't know how we make require filed in html form of magento 2.

```
<div class="field field-from">
    <label for="gift-message-whole-from" class="label">
        <span data-bind="i18n: 'From:'"></span>
    </label>
    <div class="control">
        <input type="text"
               id="gift-message-whole-from"
               class="input-text"
               data-bind="value: getObservable('sender')">
    </div>
</div>
```

I used this but not luck

method #1 – by setting data-validate attribute on the input field:

```
<input data-validate='{"required":true}'name="field1" id="field1" ... />
```

method #2 – by setting the rule names as attributes:

```
<input required="true" name="field2" id="field2" ... />
```

method #3 – by setting the rule names as classnames:

```
<input class="input-text required" name="field3" id="field3" ... />
```

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Override this template and add `required="true"` inside `<input>`. So that in your case:

```
<div class="field field-from">
    <label for="gift-message-whole-from" class="label">
        <span data-bind="i18n: 'From:'"></span>
    </label>
    <div class="control">
        <input type="text"
               id="gift-message-whole-from"
               class="input-text"
               data-bind="value: getObservable('sender')"
               required="true">
    </div>
</div>
```

Step 1 is not required in your case as the validation is loaded within the form already when the website run `vendor/magento/module-gift-message/view/frontend/templates/inline.phtml`

Ref: http://inchoo.net/magento-2/validate-custom-form-in-magento-2/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already used all 4 methods which is defind in inchoo. but still it's not validate text. I think gift option has not `validation()` passed becuse it has not <form>. any idea about this?

Comment: `vendor/magento/module-gift-message/view/frontend/templates/inline.phtml` this file are rendering in checkout not in cart page. I worked on cart. which has gift option html which is coming from `/var/www/html/georgetteklinger/vendor/magento/module-gift-message/view/frontend/web/template/gift-message-form.html` and which has not <form> and passed any validation.

Comment: i am updating /vendor/magento/module-gift-message/view/frontend/web/template/gift-message-form.html , but refresh from every where. no luck, i can't customized the form, can someone help

Comment: use aria-required="true"